# Group array values and add properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

Does anyone know a way to group an array of objects by an object key? For example, I have a number of car objects:

```
const cars = [
  "fiat-palio", 
  "fiat-stilo", 
  "fiat-strada", 
  "fiat-uno", 
  "fiat-uno", 
  "gm-corsa", 
  "gm-celta", 
  "ford-fiesta", 
  "volkswagen-gol", 
  "volkswagen-gol", 
  "volkswagen-gol", 
  "volkswagen-voyage"
]
```

I want to make a new array of car objects grouped by each automaker:

```
{ 
  "fiat": { 
    "palio": 1, 
    "stilo": 1, 
    "strada": 1, 
    "uno": 2 
  }, 
  "gm": { 
    "corsa": 1, 
    "celta": 1 
  }, 
  "ford": { 
    "fiesta": 1 
  }, 
  "volkswagen": { 
    "gol": 3, 
    "voyage": 1 
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the result that you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split each car and destruct the array to grab the make and model. After you have identified these values, just spread the values across a reducer.

```js
const cars = [
  "fiat-palio", "fiat-stilo", "fiat-strada", "fiat-uno", "fiat-uno", 
  "gm-corsa",  "gm-celta", 
  "ford-fiesta", 
  "volkswagen-gol", "volkswagen-gol", "volkswagen-gol", "volkswagen-voyage"
];

const frequency = cars.reduce((groups, car) => ({
  ...groups,
  ...(([make, model]) => ({
    [make] : {
      ...groups?.[make],
      [model] : (groups?.[make]?.[model] || 0) + 1
    }
  }))(car.split('-'))
}), {});

console.log(frequency);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Code golf fun

`f=l=>l.reduce((g,c)=>({...g,...(([m,n])=>({[m]:{...g?.[m],[n]:(g?.[m]?.[n]||0)+1}}))(c.split('-'))}),{})` (104 bytes)

**Usage:** Just pass `cars` to the `f` function above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method of array to produce desired output.

`reduce` takes arrays previous and current items on each iteration and returns scalar value. [here the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const cars = [
  "fiat-palio", 
  "fiat-stilo", 
  "fiat-strada", 
  "fiat-uno", 
  "fiat-uno", 
  "gm-corsa", 
  "gm-celta", 
  "ford-fiesta", 
  "volkswagen-gol", 
  "volkswagen-gol", 
  "volkswagen-gol", 
  "volkswagen-voyage"
];

let result = cars.reduce((obj, item) => {
  let pair = item.split('-'); // split key and value
  let mark = pair[0]; 
  let model = pair[1];

  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(mark)) { // initialize new mark and model
     obj[mark] = {};
     obj[mark][model] = 1;
  } else {
    if(obj[mark].hasOwnProperty(model)) { // increment existing model 
      obj[mark][model] += 1; 
    } else { // initialize model of existing mark
       obj[mark][model] = 1;
    }
  }

  return obj;
}, {}) 


console.log(result)
```